# Relation between [windows-scripting], [batch-file] and [cmd] tags

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

Which of the [windows-scripting](/questions/tagged/windows-scripting), [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file), and [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tags should be used when?

[Common questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7001060) with these tags are ones about some code snippet that could work interactively in the command prompt (cmd) just as it could work in a batch file.

Answer (score 5):

#### [windows-scripting](/questions/tagged/windows-scripting)

This is a pointless tag because it doesn't tell us anything useful about the question.

The only way that this tag works is if you combine it with another tag that indicates what *type* of scripting you're using on Windows (e.g., WSH, batch files, PowerShell, etc.). That is the very definition of a [meta tag](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/). So it either needs to be burninated, or perhaps synonymized with [wsh](/questions/tagged/wsh) (which is for the Windows Script Host, and appears to be what *most* of the [windows-scripting](/questions/tagged/windows-scripting) questions are about).

#### [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file)

This is the tag that you should use when the question is about batch files. It is irrelevant whether that batch file is going to generate a Command Prompt window. Once that tag is applied, everyone knows that the command interpreter is going to execute it; that's how batch files work. They also know that you're wanting the commands to work from a batch file, so all of the standard tricks and unusual maintained-for-backwards-compatibility behaviors apply.

We've done a very good job of [synonymizing all of the various tags that had cropped up](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/batch-file/synonyms) relating to batch file programming. I think this tag is useful and in good standing.

#### [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd)

This, to me, seems like a dumb tag. But I don't feel terribly strongly about that, either. Some thoughts:

Like you said, one possible use for this tag is to apply it to every question that asks about batch files. But that makes it redundant.

Another, possibly better, use is on questions that are *actually about* the Windows Command Prompt (aka console). But I'm not sure how many of those questions are [actually programming-related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17878875/in-windows-console-is-there-a-way-to-list-all-remembered-commands-that-are-in-th). (Remember, we already have tags for [console-application](/questions/tagged/console-application)s and [command-line](/questions/tagged/command-line)). If this is how the tag is going to be used, some synonymization action needs to happen between it, [command-prompt](/questions/tagged/command-prompt), [windows-console](/questions/tagged/windows-console), [console](/questions/tagged/console), and possibly some others.

But we *probably* don't need this tag at all. Most of the legitimate questions that have it either have or need to have another tag that explains *what* they're doing with the command prompt. And then there are a whole bunch of questions dealing generically with "commands" or variables named "cmd" that have it.

As long as we have this tag, though, if you want to use it on batch file questions, you can. This usage does make sense. I just don't see it as strictly necessary.

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer. I think you covered those three tags very well. However, I still wonder how to tag the question I linked. I think it is mainly about the **language** and **common commands** used in batch files; would you use [tag:batch-file] for this?

Comment: @Adrian I guess my issue is that questions about typing commands at the command prompt are not really on topic for Stack Overflow. They're not programming related (but they would be OK on Super User). The question has to be about batch file programming in order to be on topic here. So yes, I'd tag that question [tag:batch-file].

Comment: Well, the difference between programming and using is not whether it is interactive or not. But I guess many (interactive) usages of cmd are too trivial to be considered programming, right?

Comment: @Adrian Why *isn't* the distinction whether it's interactive? If you're typing commands at a command prompt, you're not doing anything programmatically. So unless it's a tool question about programming tools (i.e. source control, etc.), it's off-topic.

Comment: `sh` supports the same language whether you use it interactively or executing a script. Also, nothing prevents you from writing arbitrary complex statement sequences in interactive mode.